# How to use cTAKES from the command line?

Tags: nlp, ctakes

I wonder how to use [Apache cTAKES](http://ctakes.apache.org/) from the command line.

E.g. :

- I have a file note.txt that contains some text like "Patient had
  elevated blood sugar but tests confirm no diabetes.  Patient's father had
  adult onset diabetes."
- I want to use the provided analysis engine
  `\apache-ctakes-3.2.2-bin\apache-ctakes-3.2.2\desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextUMLSProcessor.xml`

How can I get the analyse engine's output (viz. the annotations) using the
command line (i.e. without using graphical user interfaces such as UIMA CAS
Visual Debugger or the Collection Processing Engine)? I'd prefer to
use the provided JAR files rather than having to compile the code.

The question is fairly simple but I couldn't find the information in
[cTAKES's README](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ctakes/trunk/README) or
on [Confluence](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CTAKES/cTAKES+3.0).

Answer (score 6):

Please try the following steps to use cTAKES CPE from the command line (the key class is "org.apache.uima.examples.cpe.SimpleRunCPE"):

1. Change directory to $CTAKES_HOME/desc/ctakes-clinical-pipeline/desc/collection_processing_engine/
2. Copy test_plaintext.xml to another file (e.g., "test_plaintext_test.xml").
3. Edit "test_plaintext_test.xml" to set input directory; find "nameValuePair" with name = "InputDirectory", and set the value string to the input directory. The following example set the input directory as "$CTAKES_HOME/note_input":

   ```
   <nameValuePair>
       <name>InputDirectory</name>
       <value>
           <string>note_input</string>
       </value>
   </nameValuePair>
   ```
4. Similarly, edit "test_plaintext_test.xml" to set the output directory ("$CTAKES_HOME/result_output" in the following example):

   ```
   <nameValuePair>
       <name>OutputDirectory</name>
       <value>
           <string>result_output</string>
       </value>
   </nameValuePair>
   ```
5. Save "test_plaintext_test.xml" and change directory to $CTAKES_HOME/bin.
6. Copy runctakesCPE.sh to another file (e.g., "runctakesCPE_CLI.sh").
7. Edit "runctakesCPE_CLI.sh"; replace the last line ("java ...") to the following line ("USER" and "PW" should be replaced by your UMLS Username and Password, and the memory setting Xms and Xms may be adjusted based on the size of memory on your machine):

   ```
   java -Dctakes.umlsuser=USER -Dctakes.umlspw=PW -cp $CTAKES_HOME/lib/*:$CTAKES_HOME/desc/:$CTAKES_HOME/resources/ -Dlog4j.configuration=file:$CTAKES_HOME/config/log4j.xml -Xms2g -Xmx3g org.apache.uima.examples.cpe.SimpleRunCPE $CTAKES_HOME/desc/ctakes-clinical-pipeline/desc/collection_processing_engine/test_plaintext_test.xml
   ```
8. Save "runctakesCPE_CLI.sh", and then create the input directory ("$CTAKES_HOME/note_input") and the output directory ("$CTAKES_HOME/result_output").
9. Put your note.txt to the input directory (e.g., "$CTAKES_HOME/note_input/note.txt"), and then run "runctakesCPE_CLI.sh".
10. cTAKES CPE will start running under command line mode, and the resulting file will be generated in the output directory (e.g., "$CTAKES_HOME/result_output/note.txt.xml").

I actually used your note.txt to run the steps above and here are the first several lines of the generated note.txt.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><CAS version="2">
        <uima.cas.Sofa _indexed="0" _id="3" sofaNum="1" sofaID="_InitialView" mimeType="text" sofaString="Patient had elevated blood sugar but tests confirm no diabetes. Patient's father had adult onset diabetes.&#10;"/>
        <org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.structured.DocumentID _indexed="1" _id="1" documentID="note.txt"/>
        <uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation _indexed="1" _id="10" _ref_sofa="3" begin="0" end="107" language="x-unspecified"/>
        <org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.textspan.Segment _indexed="1" _id="15" _ref_sofa="3" begin="0" end="107" id="SIMPLE_SEGMENT"/>
        <org.apache.ctakes.typesystem.type.textspan.Sentence _indexed="1" _id="21" _ref_sofa="3" begin="0" end="63" sentenceNumber="0"/>
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for the steps, but I'm getting this when I run the script "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.uima.tools.cpm.CpmFrame" Note: I'm using cygwin on windows 10

Comment: @MokhtarAshour Could you try this: java -Dctakes.umlsuser=USER -Dctakes.umlspw=PW -classpath $CTAKES_HOME/lib/*;$CTAKES_HOME/desc/;$CTAKES_HOME/resources/ -Dlog4j.configuration=file:$CTAKES_HOME/config/log4j.xml -Xms2g -Xmx3g org.apache.uima.examples.cpe.SimpleRunCPE $CTAKES_HOME/desc/ctakes-clinical-pipeline/desc/collection_processing_engine/test_plaintext_test.xml

Comment: I tried it, now it gives me "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.uima.examples.cpe.SimpleRunCPE". Do you think I should try it on linux or something?

Comment: @MokhtarAshour It looks like the problem of classpath (cannot find the correct class file). Could you try the following: java -Dctakes.umlsuser=USER -Dctakes.umlspw=PW -classpath lib/*;desc/;resources/ -Dlog4j.configuration=file:config/log4j.xml -Xms2g -Xmx3g org.apache.uima.examples.cpe.SimpleRunCPE desc/ctakes-clinical-pipeline/desc/collection_processing_engine/test_plaintext.xml

Comment: Well, I ignored the "runctakesCPE_CLI.sh" and edited the "runctakesCPE.bat" file to use the "org.apache.uima.examples.cpe.SimpleRunCPE" class and it works now. A related question, what are the possible output formats can I get from cTakes (ex: xml, json, ...) and how to get them. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`java -Dctakes.umlsuser=USER -Dctakes.umlspw=PW -cp $CTAKES_HOME/lib/*;$CTAKES_HOME/desc/;$CTAKES_HOME/resources‌​/ -
 Dlog4j.configuration=file:$CTAKES_HOME/config/log4j.xml -Xms2g -Xmx3g to_replace $CTAKES_HOME/desc/ctakes-clinical-pipeline/desc/collection_p‌​rocessing_engine/tes‌​t_plaintext_test.xml`

replace "to_replace" with either

`org.apache.ctakes.ytex.tools.RunCPE or 
org.apache.ctakes.core.cpe.CmdLineCpeRunner`

Comment: after following @Tsung-Ting Kuo's steps had  the error others were having, "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.uima.examples.cpe.SimpleRunCPE", replaced it with org.apache.ctakes.ytex.tools.RunCPE and it works well!

Comment: Was anyone able to run SideEffectSentenceCPE.xml with this approach?